# Where can I see what version of Tails I have?

Tags: tails, update

Since Tails only reports when it fails to upgrade, not when it succeeds I want to know where I can check to see if I have the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tails Upgrader](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/upgrade/index.en.html#index1h1) should run automatically when Tails connects to the Tor network after startup. There shouldn't be a need to check the version manually: Tails should keep itself up to date.

If, for whatever reason, your system was unable to connect to the Tor network at startup (e.g. if you didn't have a network connection), then you can run the upgrader manually from the command line using `tails-upgrade-frontend-wrapper`.

The upgrader will tell you if your version is out of date.

If you really just want to check the version without relying on the upgrader, then run the following: `cat /etc/amnesia/version`.

Comment: If I type `cat/etc/amnesia/version` I get the error message "No  such file or directory".

Comment: `cat` is a command. There should be a space between that and the file path. Can you confirm that's what you've tried?

Comment: Oh, I see. That explains it. :-)